# SEO и AJAX

Tags: seo, ajax

У меня есть [блог](http://blog.devhelper.ru/) на Wordpress. При нажатии на любую ссылку идет загрузка контента с помощью технологии AJAX. Я хочу задать вопрос - как это отразится на SEO (продвижении сайта)? Или лучше убрать подгрузку страниц Аяксом?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Индексация AJAX сайтов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/284773/%d0%98%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-ajax-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Индексирование AJAX сайтов [Яндексом](http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/?id=1125296) и [Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/)

Answer (score 1):

если сайт полностью работоспособен без javascript, то на индексацию страниц роботами это никак не отобразится. Только, что статистика будет показывать меньше хитов)