# Индексация AJAX сайтов

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-search, яндекс-поиск

Я уже читал о индексации AJAX сайтов на [Yandex Help](http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/robot-workings/ajax-indexing.xml) и [GoogleSupport](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/81766?hl=ru), но у меня структура уже не позволяет делать глобальные изменения.

Если я сделаю определение `USER_AGENT` на `GoogleBot` или `YandexBot`(названия могут быть не точными), в PHP скриптах, и подменю полностью сайт на HTML версию, будут ли мои ссылки индексироваться и появляться в поисковике?

Comment: вы лучше сделайте определение заголовка 

    X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

и если его нет, значит этот запрос не ajax.

Comment: Как мне это поможет? Если у меня сайт весь в AJAX, у меня по сути сайт - 1 страница рабочая.

Comment: ну как, обращаемся без ajax к контроллеру - показываем не ajax вьюху. (я про что - это ответ на вопрос "будет ли..." если доступа к контенту по ссылке нет, то и индексироваться не будет (на самом деле они крутят конечно js у себя в роботах, но не так чтобы прям всё что угодно).

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы обеспечить индексацию SPA (Sinlge Page Apps), лучше всего использовать [изоморфные](http://habrahabr.ru/post/203444/) [решения](http://habrahabr.ru/post/259625/). Это такие фреймворки/библиотеки, которые умеют строить страницы как на клиенте, так и на сервере. Лучший вариант сейчас - это React.js + Flux, и хорошей альтернативой в будущем будет Angular2.

Answer (score 0):

Поставили как то задачу чтобы музыка беспрерывно на сайте звучала. Также с помощью AJAX'а были созданы переходы по сайту. Для индексации поисковыми ботами создали дублирующий контроллер который выдавал страницы в зависимости от GET данных.
Создали sitemap для индексации поисковыми ботами. В итоге при заходе бота по любой ссылке из sitemap, выдавался соответствующий контент. При переходе из поисковой выдачи, пользователь попадал на нужную страницу, а дальше уже через AJAX совершал переходы по сайту.
Более подробно рассказать не смогу так как такую систему создавать придётся в зависимости от имеющегося кода.