# Индексация ajax сайта

Tags: ajax, seo, поисковые-системы

есть сайт **example.ru**

Есть страница **index.html**

Навигация сайта сделана на **ajax** (контент грузится динамически) на index.html

Когда пользователь переходит по пунктам меню, то в url с помощью **history Api** меняется хэши вида

**example.ru/product**

**example.ru/price**

**example.ru/about**

Если пользователь перезагружает страницу, находясь например на странице
по **example.ru/price** - то nginx редиректит такой запрос на **index.html**, и на этой странице берется url и ajax опять грузит контент.

Как сделать такие страницы индексируемыми?

Посмотрел у яндекса у них нужно добавлять **#!** в url и вебсервером отдавать страницы  **http://www.example.ru/?_escaped_fragment_=blog**

Собственно 2 вопроса:

1. Мне нужно переделывать свои роуты с **example.ru/price** на **example.com/#!** price или можно оставить как есть и использовать другой вариант?
2. Как настроить **nginx** на отдачу статичного контента?
   у меня должна быть директория где лежит полностью отдельная страничка вроде **price.html** или как?

Comment: К сожалению, не могу прикрепить с телефона ссылку. Но в русском Stackoverflow уже есть подобные вопросы. Поищите "ajax индексация"

Comment: На самом деле непонятно как сделать чтобы 

http://example.ru/prices → http://example.ru/prices?_escaped_fragment_=, если у меня все запросы редиректиться на index.html

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Индексация AJAX сайтов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/284773/%d0%98%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-ajax-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)